# inquiry about differential geometry texts.

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question

i am very interested in diff geometry as a math undergraduate student and want to study the diff geometry in the graduate school. so what would be a good book for the advanced diff geometry to get some glimpse into the current researches on the diff geometry so that i can learn more about it and have some words to say in sop? i am currently reading the professor tu's an introduction to manifolds.

Comment: It is my experience that a lot of people struggle with the idea of abstract vector fields, differential forms, and tensor fields when they are first introduced to them.   As such, I would recommend Barret O'Neill's text Elementary Differential Geometry.  The text introduces frame fields and differential forms in the context of the geometry three-dimensional Euclidean space  and it sharpens the students intuition for working abstractly with differential forms.  There are of course other wonderful differential geometry texts (DoCarmo, Andrew Pressley, Wolfgang Kuhnel, etc.) . . .

Comment: . . . and you are best to consult several at once so that you can learn different perspectives on the subject, but I would strongly recommend any student to use their familiarity with Euclidean space to develop intuition and comfort for and with frame fields and differential forms.

Comment: For classical differential geometry you can try Millman and Parker's text, Elements of Differential Geometry. This is merely for intuition purposes. You can also simulatenously read Lee's book on smooth manifolds. I'm not sure how it compares to Tu's book, but I really like the exposition. Then to get into Riemannian Geometry you could try Lee's text on Riemannian manifolds or do Carmo's. I think Lee is actually coming out with a second edition. Hopefully, it presents the material in the vector bundle approach though I am uncertain of that at the moment.

Comment: Once you have some background(i.e. know a sizeable portion of Lee's Riemannian manifolds text) you can take a look at Peterson's text on Riemmanian Geometry. That book has a lot of material, so you definitely won't be bored going through it. If your interested in the vector bundle approach to Riemannian geometry you can also try Takashi Sakai's text on Riemmanian Geometry.

Comment: Thank you people. Your comments helped me a lot. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I always recommend J.Jost's "differential geometry and geometric analysis" to those who have some understanding in DG and wish to have a board introduction.